# Margin Figures in Latex

Tags: latex, figure

I would like to put some figures in margin in my latex documents. I want them to be non-float. Is there any package for it.

thanks

Answer (score 17):

Use the caption package:

```
\usepackage{caption}
```

and e.g.

```
\marginpar{%
  \includegraphics[width=\marginparwidth]{myfile}
  \captionof{figure}{The caption}
}
```